# iOS App Goes Dim

Tags: ios, screen

Very difficult issue to figure out...this only happens on a real device not plugged in.  When my app loads up to the main view, i show a wait dialog while a few background threads fire off and search for products.  this takes about 5-7 seconds.  If I load the app and about 1-3 seconds in, i close the app and go to another app, then come back to my app, the screen dims around the edges and the app just freezes.

I did a few google searches for this screen dimming and couldn't find anything

The app never crashes.

Comment: Looks like you have some UIAlertView problem, it has a dimmed background - do you have any supposed to be shown ?

Comment: Good thinking, yeah that might be it, i will take it out and let u know

Comment: yeah app was hitting a part of code that showed the UIAlertView but from within a non-UI thread...thanks man

Comment: np, you can write a short answer & accept it to prevent the accept-rate from running low.